# How to use WHERE clause with ON query?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

While working with left join I wanted to have a search string parameter - which would be dynamic. So, I had the following queries

```
 pl_ids_tuple = 1477    //Playlist id
 initial_query_string = '''select songs.id, songs.name, songs.artist, songs.album, songs.albumart, songs."albumartThumbnail", cpr.votes, is_requested from
            (select id, name, artist, album, albumart, "albumartThumbnail" from (select song_id from core_plsongassociation where playlist_id in (%s))'''%pl_ids_tuple

 songs = Song.objects.raw(initial_query_string + ''' as sinpl
                        left join songs on sinpl.song_id=id where explicit=False
                    ) as songs left join
                    (select song_id, votes, bool_or(thirdpartyuser_id=%s) as is_requested from
                        (select * from core_priorityrequests where client_id=%s and is_played=False
                        ) as clpr left join core_priorityrequests_third_party_user on clpr.id=priorityrequests_id
                        group by priorityrequests_id, song_id, votes
                ) as cpr on songs.id=cpr.song_id where songs.name ilike %s or songs.artist ilike %s limit %s offset %s
                left join
                (select core_blocksong.song_id from core_blocksong where core_blocksong.unblock_flag = 'f' and core_blocksong.client_id=%s)
                as c on c.song_id = songs.id where c.song_id is null''',
                                         [request.anon_user.id, restaurant.client.id,search_string,search_string,limit,offset,restaurant.client.id,])
```

If you notice/observe closely I get a programming error due to the placement of - `songs.name ilike %s or songs.artist ilike %s limit %s offset %s` in the query.

If I put this constraint in the end, then the response is different. Can anyone suggest where can I put this constraint in order to get the correct response?

I read through this resource - https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx/ and found that where filters after joining.

Comment: @JoeHolloway could you please help?

Comment: What's `initial_query_string`? If you're doing this much `.raw()`, this isn't really a Django question but a basic SQL question.

Comment: @AKX actually this is just a part of Django code. Therefore, I mentioned Django. Have added  - initial_query_string.